# Change user password in strapi

Tags: strapi

Strapi has the `user-permission` plugin where it has an endpoint to reset a forgotten password. But I would like to change a known password (as a user) in which sending an email with a verification token is not necessary. In Strapi documentation for the user-permission plugin, I didn't come across such an endpoint. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

After inspecting the `user-permission` plugin's code I implemented a simpler solution instead of extending the plugin. For this, I created a custom controller (and route) as following:

**/api/custom/controllers/custom.js**

```js
    'use strict';
    const _ = require('lodash');
    const { sanitizeEntity } = require('strapi-utils');
    
    const sanitizeUser = user =>
      sanitizeEntity(user, {
        model: strapi.query('user', 'users-permissions').model,
      });
    
    module.exports = {
      async changePassword(ctx) {
        const userFromContext = ctx.state.user;
    
        if (!userFromContext) {
          return ctx.badRequest(null, [{ messages: [{ id: 'No authorization header was found' }] }]);
        }
    
        const params = _.assign({}, ctx.request.body);
        if (
          params.currentPassword &&
          params.newPassword &&
          params.confirmNewPassword &&
          params.newPassword === params.confirmNewPassword
        ) {
    
          const user = await strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.user.fetch({
            id: userFromContext.id,
          }, ['role']);
    
          const validPassword = await strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.user.validatePassword(params.currentPassword, user.password);
    
          if (!user) {
            return ctx.badRequest('User does not exist');
          }
    
          if (!validPassword) {
            return ctx.badRequest('Old password does not match.')
          }
    
          let updateData = { password: params.newPassword };
          const data = await strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.user.edit({ id: user.id }, updateData);
          return ctx.send(sanitizeUser(data));
        }
    
        return ctx.badRequest('New passwords do not match.');
      }
    };
```

**/api/custom/config/routes.json**

```json
    {
      "routes": [
        {
          "method": "POST",
          "path": "/custom/change-password",
          "handler": "custom.changePassword",
          "config": {
            "policies": []
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Now I can POST an authenticated request to `http://localhost:1337/custom/change-password` with the following body in order to change the password for a logged-in user:

```json
    {
      "currentPassword": "Abcd1234",
      "newPassword": "Abcde12345",
      "confirmNewPassword": "Abcde12345"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Anyone reading this now, I had this issue but it was because I was using an older version of Strapi. Upgrading to 4.3.3 or higher should sort it.